# Ошибка преобразования SigningCredentials при генерации JWT

Tags: asp.net-web-api

Добрый вечер.

Возникает **Ошибка** компиляции: не удается преобразовать из `Thinktecture.IdentityModel.Tokens.HmacSigningCredentials` в `Microsoft.IdentityModel.Tokens.SigningCredentials`

"Ругается" на `signingKey`.

**Здесь:**

```
  var token = new JwtSecurityToken(_issuer, audienceId, data.Identity.Claims, issued.Value.UtcDateTime, expires.Value.UtcDateTime, signingKey);
```

Полное описание:

```
 using Microsoft.Owin.Security.DataHandler.Encoder;
 using System;
 using System.Configuration;
 using System.IdentityModel.Tokens;
 using System.IdentityModel.Tokens.Jwt;
 using System.Text;
 using Microsoft.Owin.Security;
 using Thinktecture.IdentityModel.Tokens;

   public class CustomJwtFormat : ISecureDataFormat<AuthenticationTicket>
{
    private readonly string _issuer;

    public CustomJwtFormat(string issuer)
    {
        _issuer = issuer;
    }

    public string Protect(AuthenticationTicket data)
    {
        if (data == null)
        {
            throw new ArgumentNullException(nameof(data));
        }

        var audienceId = ConfigurationManager.AppSettings["as:AudienceId"];
        var symmetricKeyAsBase64 = ConfigurationManager.AppSettings["as:AudienceSecret"];
        var keyByteArray = TextEncodings.Base64Url.Decode(symmetricKeyAsBase64);

        var signingKey =  new HmacSigningCredentials(keyByteArray);

        var issued = data.Properties.IssuedUtc;
        var expires = data.Properties.ExpiresUtc;

        if (issued == null || expires == null)
            return null;

        var token = new JwtSecurityToken(_issuer, audienceId, data.Identity.Claims, issued.Value.UtcDateTime, expires.Value.UtcDateTime, signingKey);
        var handler = new JwtSecurityTokenHandler();
        var jwt = handler.WriteToken(token);
        return jwt;
    }
```

Comment: *Так может, там и правда преобразовать нельзя?..*

Comment: Это ошибка компиляции. Может посоветуете какой стек библиотек лучше использовать?

Comment: Не посоветую, ибо не сталкивался. Но выглядит как будто перемешаны библиотеки для .net framework и .net core. Укажите, пожалуйста, какие библиотеки вы используете сейчас.

Comment: @PavelMayorov поправил.